# Turning background to one color

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I have an RGB image that I want to do segmentation with using thresholding. I want some objects to be white, while the background should be blue. How can I accomplish this?

I've tried using for loops, but not sure how to do iterate through RGB images properly.

Comment: Do you know which pixels are background pixels and which aren't?

Comment: can you post an example image you are working on?

Comment: This is very broad; you should start [here](http://www.mathworks.com/discovery/image-segmentation.html).  Specifically, try the first walkthrough with Otsu's method (`graythresh`) of finding a threshold automatically , then try k-means, etc.  You will need to learn your data to figure out the right solution.  For example, it may be necessary to smooth the image first, maybe a simple `edge` detection with Canny is sufficient...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterating through the image depends on the language, data structure used etc...  The following pseudo-code may help for simple thresholding of pixels greater than some value.  You seem to indicate you're interested in multichannel data, so you might need to check each channel and set the result to blue/white accordingly.

```
## image thresholding pseudo code

imagea = ReadImage('yourfilehere')
outputImage = zeros(imagea.shape)
threshold = 100
for i in range(imagea.shape[0]):
  for j in range(imagea.shape[1]):
    pixelValue = GetPixel(imagea,i,j)
    if pixelValue>100:
      SetPixel(outputImage,i,j,255)
    else:
      SetPixel(outputImage,i,j,0)
```